# Attempting to compare two values of type V with Go generics not working

Tags: go, generics

Go version: go1.21rc2

I'm writing a function using generics in Go, that takes a value and returns true/false if the value is in the map.

In version 1 below, I don't understand why the two values can't be compared when they're of type `any`? But after casting to type `any` in version 2, it now works... I assume I've missed something obvious but I don't really understand this.

Version 1 (NOT WORKING):

```golang
func InValues[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M, v V) bool {
    for _, x := range maps.Values(m) {
        if x == v {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Version 2 (WORKING):

```golang
func InValues[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M, v V) bool {
    for _, x := range maps.Values(m) {
        if any(x) == any(v) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Your second version _compiles_ and works for _some_ cases because interface values are comparable but probably isn't what you _want_. You basically cannot use any as constraint for V (you have to use comparable) and even then your code will be broken unless you _really_ do some hard work to make it correct (e.g. for float64).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`V` needs to be `comparable` for `==` to be allowed.
The cast to `any` and then comparison works because then it uses the non generic `==` between `any` which is always allowed.

Comment: There are no casts in Go, it's a conversion to any.